# Get http status code in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-status-codes

So, i'm trying to get the http status code of an URL that i pass to the funcion. so far i've used the request module but the problem is that request fetches all the content of the given URL and if the content is a big amount of data it's slow, but i just need to get the status code to make an if statement.

```
request(audioURL, function (error, response) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        queue.push({
            title: videoTitle, 
            user: message.author.username, 
            mention: message.author.mention(), 
            url: audioURL
        });

        bot.reply(message, "\"" + videoTitle + "\" has been added to the queue.")
    }
    else {
        bot.reply(message, "Sorry, I couldn't get the audio track for that video. HTTP status code: " + response.statusCode);
    }
});
```

This is what i got so far.audioURL is a basic string with a link to a media file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.request` can take an `options` Object as its first parameter. Use something like this:

```
const options = {
    method: 'HEAD',
    host: 'example.com',
};

const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.headers));
});

req.end();
```

The problem is that you'll want to turn your `audioURL` into its components, to pass as parameters of `options`. I'm using the `HEAD` method, that fetches only the headers of your request.